# d3.line not generating output for linechart

Tags: d3.js

I tried console.log, various combinations nothing seems to work. It's almost like the line generator never receives the data.  Using d3v5.js.  Appreciate any insight into this.  I checked out and applied many of the instances of this on this site but none worked for my implementation.

The data I am using:

```
let massdata = {
    Years: [1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008,
        2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017],
    USAttacks: [2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 7, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
}
```

My line generator

```
// line generator
let line = d3.line()
    .x( function(d) {console.log(xScale(d.x)); return xScale(d.x);}) // set the x values for the line generator
    .y( function(d) {return yScale(d.y);}) // set the y values for the line generator
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX); // apply smoothing to the line
```

xScale and yScale

```
let xScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([x_min,x_max])
    .range([0, width]);

let yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, y_max])
    .range([height, 0]);
```

The piece that is suppose to apply the line:

```
// Append the path, bind the data, and call the line generator
svg.append("path")
    .datum(data) // Binds data to the line
    .attr("class", "line") // Assign a class for styling
    .attr("d", line); // Calls the line generator
```

```js
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

let massdata = {
  Years: [1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008,
    2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017
  ],
  USAttacks: [2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 7, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
}

let margin = {
    top: 50,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 60
  },
  width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

let fmtDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

let years = massdata.Years.map(y => y + "-1-1");
let dates = years.map(d => fmtDate(d));

let data = {
  x: dates,
  y: massdata.USAttacks
};

let y_max = Math.max.apply(Math, data.y);
let y_min = Math.min.apply(Math, data.y);
let y_labels = data.y.filter(onlyUnique);
let x_max = dates[dates.length - 1];
let x_min = dates[0];

let xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([x_min, x_max])
  .range([0, width]);

let yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, y_max])
  .range([height, 0]);

let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(d3.timeYear.every(1));
let yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickValues(y_labels);

// line generator
let line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    console.log(xScale(d.x));
    return xScale(d.x);
  }) // set the x values for the line generator
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScale(d.y);
  }) // set the y values for the line generator
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX); // apply smoothing to the line

let svg = d3.select("#linechart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);
svg.append("text")
  .attr("class", "axis-label")
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", "-3.4em")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .text('Yearly Attacks');

// Append the path, bind the data, and call the line generator
svg.append("path")
  .datum(data) // Binds data to the line
  .attr("class", "line") // Assign a class for styling
  .attr("d", line); // Calls the line generator
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ffab00;
  stroke-width: 3;
}

path {
  stroke: steelblue;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid path,
.grid line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="linechart">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an array of objects as input instead of using an object with 2 arrays. As a quick fix you could use this transformation of the input data to make it work:

```
let linedata = data.x.map(function(value, i) {
    return {x: data.x[i], y: data.y[i]};
});

svg.append("path")
  .datum(linedata)
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", line);
```

What it does is transforming this object:

```
{x: [0, 1], y: [0, 1]}
```

Into this array of objects:

```
[{x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 1, y: 1}]
```

```js
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

let massdata = {
  Years: [1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008,
    2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017
  ],
  USAttacks: [2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 7, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
}

let margin = {
    top: 50,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 60
  },
  width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
let fmtDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

let years = massdata.Years.map(y => y + "-1-1");
let dates = years.map(d => fmtDate(d));

let data = {
  x: dates,
  y: massdata.USAttacks
};

let y_max = Math.max.apply(Math, data.y);
let y_min = Math.min.apply(Math, data.y);
let y_labels = data.y.filter(onlyUnique);
let x_max = dates[dates.length - 1];
let x_min = dates[0];

let xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([x_min, x_max])
  .range([0, width]);

let yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, y_max])
  .range([height, 0]);

let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(d3.timeYear.every(1));
let yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickValues(y_labels);

// line generator
let line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return xScale(d.x);
  }) // set the x values for the line generator
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScale(d.y);
  }) // set the y values for the line generator
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX); // apply smoothing to the line

let svg = d3.select("#linechart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);
svg.append("text")
  .attr("class", "axis-label")
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", "-3.4em")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .text('Yearly Attacks');

let linedata = data.x.map(function(value, i) {
  return {
    x: data.x[i],
    y: data.y[i]
  };
});

// Append the path, bind the data, and call the line generator
svg.append("path")
  .datum(linedata) // Binds data to the line
  .attr("class", "line") // Assign a class for styling;
  .attr("d", line); // Calls the line generator
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ffab00;
  stroke-width: 3;
}

path {
  stroke: steelblue;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid path,
.grid line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="linechart">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow completely forgotten it needed x,y pairs. Wish the docs were more clear on that.

Comment: @AmazingGrace It does not need x/y pairs. And the docs are perfectly clear: the data needs to be an **array**.